# Update accessToken on 401 and repeat request with a new token

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I am trying to implement a scenario which is supposed to be very common: send request with `WebClient` and if it fails with `401` then refresh `accessToken` in `TokenSupplier`, update auth header in the request with a refreshed token and retry the request.

TokenSupplier:
I have two methods because I was experimenting with different approaches:

`refreshToken()` - supposed to do all the job: get new token and update it in the supplier. So that when a new request is built on retry, header would get updated value.
But I got `block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2` error saying that using `block()` is not allowed.

`getNewToken()` - is the result of the second attempt. I tried to execute it in the filter function. It is the second variant of the main client below. But the header doesn't get updated and remains `null`.

```
public class TokenSupplier {
    private final WebClient webClient;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String accessToken;

    public TokenSupplier(ApplicationProperties appProps) {
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(appProps.getAuthUrl())
            .defaultHeaders(header -> header.setBasicAuth(appProps.getAuthTokenName(), appProps.getAuthTokenPassword()))
            .build();
    }
    
    public Mono<AccessToken> getNewToken() {
        return webClient
            .post()
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("grant_type", "client_credentials"))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(AccessToken.class);
    }

    public void refreshToken() {
        AccessToken accessToken = webClient
            .post()
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("grant_type", "client_credentials"))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(AccessToken.class)
            .block();

        this.setAccessToken(accessToken);
    }
}
```

The main client looks like this for variant with `refreshToken()` (for this one execution fails with `block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2`)

```
public class Client {
    private final WebClient webClient;
    private final TokenSupplier tokenSupplier;

    public Client(ApplicationProperties appProps) {
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(appProps.getRequestUrl()).build();
        this.tokenSupplier = new TokenSupplier(appProps);
    }

    public SomeResponseDTO getAppProperties() {
        return Mono.defer(() -> webClient
            .post()
            .headers(header -> header.setBearerAuth(this.tokenSupplier.getAccessToken()))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(Map.of("query", "someQuery)))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(SomeResponseDTO.class))
            .retryWhen(RetrySpec.max(1)
                .filter(e -> e instanceof WebClientResponseException.Unauthorized)
                .doBeforeRetry(retrySignal -> {
                    this.tokenSupplier.refreshToken();
                }))
            .block();
    }
}
```

This is the second approach inspired by [Springs documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient/client-filter.html)
It also doesn't work and fails with `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized from POST` . When I log request I see that the header remains `null`.

```
public class Client {
    private final WebClient webClient;
    private final TokenSupplier tokenSupplier;

    public Client(ApplicationProperties appProps) {
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(appProps.getRequestUrl())
            .filter(renewTokenFilter())
            .build();
        this.tokenSupplier = new TokenSupplier(appProps);
    }

    public SomeResponseDTO getAppProperties() {
        return Mono.defer(() -> webClient
            .post()
            .headers(header -> header.setBearerAuth(this.tokenSupplier.getAccessToken()))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(Map.of("query", "someQuery")))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(SomeResponseDTO.class))
            .block();
    }

    public ExchangeFilterFunction renewTokenFilter() {
        return (request, next) -> next.exchange(request).flatMap(response -> {
            if (response.statusCode().value() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value()) {
                return response.releaseBody()
                    .then(this.tokenSupplier.getNewToken())
                    .flatMap(token -> {
                        this.tokenSupplier.setAccessToken(token.accessToken);
                        ClientRequest newRequest = ClientRequest.from(request).build();
                        return next.exchange(newRequest);
                    });
            } else {
                return Mono.just(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I know that WebClient is supposed to be non-blocking, but it **should** wait in this scenario till token is refreshed before making retry. How can I achieve this? Those answers to similar questions which I found looked similar to mine (will fail with the same error) or were omitting some details which I cannot grasp.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I needed to explicitly update the header in the request obtained from `ClientRequest.from(request)` in the second approach. In the end it looks like this:

```
    public ExchangeFilterFunction renewTokenFilter() {
        return (request, next) -> next.exchange(request).flatMap(response -> {
            if (response.statusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {
                return response.releaseBody()
                    .then(this.tokenSupplier.getNewToken())
                    .flatMap(token -> {
                        this.tokenSupplier.setAccessToken(token.accessToken);
                        ClientRequest newRequest = ClientRequest
                            .from(request)
                            .headers(headers -> headers.setBearerAuth(token.accessToken))
                            .build();
                        return next.exchange(newRequest);
                    });
            } else {
                return Mono.just(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

But I think that this violets the `SRP` principle: I don't like that a new access token is set from within a client application - it is solely TokenSupplier's responsibility. That's why I wanted to make it as in the first approach with a blocking call to `refreshToken()` in TokenSupplier which does both: refreshes the token and resets it internally. I would appreciate if someone could advise me how to do it.